Moving (PyQt6) window not working when python file is compiled with PyInstaller on Linux Fedora
I'm trying to compile a python program. The UI is made with PyQt6, and the main window is frameless. I wanted to implement moving the window manually by using the move() function of a QWidget. When running the Python code itself, it works, but when I compile the code with PyInstaller, the window no longer moves. I have boiled down the problem to this minimal example:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 300)
    window.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
    window.show()
    screen_geometry = app.primaryScreen().geometry()
    window.move(screen_geometry.width() - window.width(), 0)
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I am compiling the code with PyInstaller: pyinstaller --onefile test.py.
The window.move() function is supposed to move the window to the right side of the screen. When running this as Python code, it works, but after compiling on Linux (Fedora), it no longer does. I tried compiling it on MacOS, and it did work there. So that leads me to believe it's a backend issue.
Edit: When I run the python code from the terminal, it doesn't work, but when I run it in VS Code, it does somehow work.
I only have a basic understanding of PyQt and I don't know anything about graphics backends, so I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I'm on Linux Fedora 40, if that's relevant. Any suggestions, explanations or insights? Thanks!

Just a hunch (as I've not enough experience with mp): when running the code in VS, it is a spawned child process, and the window manager considers the new window as "related" to those of VS, thus allowing geometry setting. In general, explicitly setting window geometries (especially for new ones) on Linux is not reliable, if not even unsupported in some cases (as also explained in the X11 Peculiarities notes); that's even more unreliable/unsupported on Wayland (unless the compositor explicitly provides support through custom APIs).

Furthermore, remember that IDEs usually run programs within an "artificial" sandboxed environment, which can be misleading: the only reliable way to finally test programs is by running them from outside of the IDE, possibly from a terminal. You could try to use a QTimer.singleShot() to delay the move call, but, as the docs linked above explain, there's no way to know when a window has been finally "mapped" on the window manager, which could even ignore geometry requests in certain conditions.

Oh, according to the docs you linked it's just not possible on Wayland... that's a bummer. Anyways, thanks for the clarification!

It's not "not possible": it is as long as the running compositor provides it and/or you're using its API. Unfortunately, due to the complexity of Wayland (and the intrinsic extensibility of Linux) that can't be easily be achieved on that platform, also because it allows the window manager to completely manage window geometries (as it was possible with X to begin with, for instance using tiling window managers, opposed to stacking ones). You may try it, but there's no certainty about it being able to work, as it wasn't even before Wayland.
